# restoring the edittext field on clicking back button

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
EditText , PatientInfo,PatientAge,PatientId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
    Button buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
    Button buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);
    Button buttonCapturePreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Capturecamerapreview);

    rgGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGender);
    rdbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbMale);
    rdbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbFemale);

    PatientInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PatientName);
    PatientInfo.setHint("enter patient name");
    PatientAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Age);
    PatientAge.setHint("Age");
    PatientId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PatientId);
    PatientId.setHint("PatientId");

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this)

     rawCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 

        {   
            loadInput();
            int imageNum = 0;
            String Name = PatientInfo.getText().toString();
                 String Age =  PatientAge.getText().toString();
                String Id = PatientId.getText().toString();         

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             Date d = new Date();
             CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
             Rname = s.toString() +".jpg";
 File imagesFolders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Name + Age + gender + Id);
             imagesFolders.mkdirs();
            File output = new File(imagesFolders, Rname);
  Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {

                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "Image saved: ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
 }
  buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
 {
  ........
 }
 buttonCapturePreview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {...}
 buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
  ......}

  public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    switch(view.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.rdbMale:
            if (checked)
                gender= "M";
                gender1="M";
            rdbFemale.setChecked(false);

            break;
        case R.id.rdbFemale:
            if (checked)
                gender = "F";
            gender1="F";
            rdbMale.setChecked(false);

            break;
    }
    }
      Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

         finish();  
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         saveInput();
         startActivity(intent);



        }

    });
}
protected void saveInput()
{ 
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
preferences.edit().putString("Name",PatientInfo.getText().toString()).commit();  
preferences.edit().putString("Age", PatientAge.getText().toString()).commit(); 
preferences.edit().putString("Id",PatientId.getText().toString()).commit(); 

}
private void loadInput(){

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String savedTextN = preferences.getString("Name", null);
    String savedTextA = preferences.getString("Age", null);
    String savedTextI = preferences.getString("Id", null);
    PatientInfo.setText(savedTextN);   
    PatientAge.setText(savedTextA);
    PatientId.setText(savedTextI);
   System.out.println(savedTextN);
   System.out.println(savedTextA);
   System.out.println(savedTextI);
}
```

i am trying to load the same data that i entered in my first activity. On button click the data is lodt. So i used shared preferences. But am using it first time so there is something wrong in my code. I just tried to load one of the edittext. Anyone can point out whats the mistake

Comment: Check out my answer and try accordingly.

Comment: you can use Log or system.out.println in loadInput() , u need to log : savedTextN, savedTextA and savedTextI variable

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. the wrong things are

1. to just restoring a data you are trying to restart the whole activity.
2. you are calling the onResume method by yourself..

Dont do these . you can do it easily by following.

1. create a method which will do the initial data setting tasks for your.
2. in onResume of you method (or in oncreate ) call that method
3. whenever you want to reset data (i.e after back button pressed) call that method.

Comment: Can you please check it once more i have edited it..i used a methon saveinput which  is called when pressing back button and in on create i am calling loadinput to restore the saved input. Is ther something wrong in it

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly getting the data from your preferences with the Wrong key.

As you are storing the value in preferences with the key `Name` in your `onResume` method and in your `loadInput` method you are trying to fetch it with the `PatientInfo` key which is not available in your preferences.

Change your `loadInput` method as below:

```
private void loadInput(){

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String savedText = preferences.getString("Name");
    PatientInfo.setText(savedText);   
}
```

As the `onResume` method always gets called before the `onCreate` so you need to initialize your `PatientInfo` view in your `onResume` method and then try to store its value into the Preferences.

Comment: @GrlsHu i have edited my answer i know that i have to call loadInput method in onCreate method but am not sure where is the exact place to call it inorder to laod the saved data

Comment: @user3040168 Can you post your whole activity please?

Comment: @user3040168 Are you sure you are again starting `MainActivity` on Back button press from this line ? `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: @user3040168 Change your backbutton code like this. `saveInput();Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);startActivity(intent);finish();`

Comment: @GrlsHu but where it is loading the input....what i am trying to do is in main activity on taking picture a folder is created with a name,age,gender,id and image is saved in that folder + it goes to another activity. here when i press back button i want to take the picture again and the image has to be saved in same folder. a new folder shud be created only when i enter a new name